# Sorting an array in minimum cost

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have an array A[] with 4 element A={
8 1 2 4 }. How to sort it with minimized cost. Criteria is defined as follows-

> a.  It is possible to swap any 2 element.
>
> b.  The cost of any swap is sum of the element value , Like if i swap 8 and 4 the cost is 12 an resultant        array is look like A={4 1 2 8}, which is still unsorted so more swap needed.
>
> c.  Need to find a way to sort the array with minimum cost.

From my observation greedy will not work, like in each step place any element to its sorted position in array with minimum cost. So a DP solution needed.
Can any one help??

Comment: I fail to see how a DP solution would be constructed. There is no obvious way one could break it down into subproblems. I can however see a solution in terms of a search problem. It will be an exhaustive search though.

Comment: That's a funny way of calculating 'costs'

Comment: Is really no DP solution exist???

Comment: The element value is positive and less than 1000. The number of element may be upto 1000.

Comment: I don't see any restriction on space... So the algorithm can be O(n) and create a separate index? (it would need do create a B array with the same size as A)

Comment: You need to sort this particular array or is it just an exampple? Are there any restrictions on linear order to pick? it is has to be from lowest to highest or other or you can pick?

Comment: @xanatos:No there is no memory restriction. You can use auxiliary array.

Comment: @ Michał Šrajer: This is just an example. yea, it need to be ascending order. Swap between any 2 element in the array can be done.

Comment: @Ben,  imagine the numbers are counts of really heavy items, where you need to hire a truck for each unit.  The minimum cost of the truck is much greater than  incidental charges for distance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swap 2 and 1, and then 1 and 4, and then 1 and 8? Or is it a general question?

For a more general approach you could try:

1. Swapping every pair of 2 elements (with the highest sum) if they are perfect swaps (i.e. swapping them will put them both at their right spot). Th
2. Use the lowest element as a pivot for swaps (by swapping the element whose spot it occupies), until it reaches its final spot
3. Then, you have two possibilities:

   1. Repeat step 2: use the lowest element not in its final spot as a pivot until it reaches its final spot, then go back to step 3
   2. Or swap the lowest element not in its final spot (l2) with the lowest element (l1), repeat step 2 until l1 reaches the final spot of l2. Then:

      1. Either swap l1 and l2 again, go to step 3.1
      2. Or go to step 3.2 again, with the next lowest element not in its final spot being used.

When all this is done, if some opposite swaps are performed one next to another (for example it could happen from going to step 2. to step 3.2.), remove them.

There are still some things to watch out for, but this is already a pretty good approximation. Step one and two should always work though, step three would be the one to improve in some borderline cases.

Example of the algorithm being used:

**With {8 4 5 3 2 7}: (target array {2 3 4 5 7 8})**

- Step 2: 2 <> 7, 2 <> 8
- Array is now {2, 4, 5, 3, 7, 8}
- Choice between 3.1 and 3.2:

  - 3.1 gives 3 <> 5, 3 <> 4
  - 3.2 gives 2 <> 3, 2 <> 5, 2 <> 4, 2 <> 3
  - 3 <> 5, 3 <> 4 is the better result

Conclusion: 2 <> 7, 2 <> 8, 3 <> 5, 3 <> 4 is the best answer.

**With {1 8 9 7 6} (resulting array {1 6 7 8 9})**

- You're beginning at step three already
- Choice between 3.1 and 3.2:

  - 3.1 gives 6 <> 9, 6 <> 7, 6 <> 8 (total: 42)
  - 3.2 gives 1 <> 6, 1 <> 9, 1 <> 7, 1 <> 8, 1 <> 6 (total: 41)

So 1 <> 6, 1 <> 9, 1 <> 7, 1 <> 8, 1 <> 6 is the best result

Comment: I have problem of understanding ur answer well, it will be better if you give an example. suppose 
A={8 4 5 3 2 7} .

Comment: Step 1 looks good, its helpful. But swaping with the lowest element does not generate optimal answer.

Comment: Step 1 looks good, its helpful. But swaping with the lowest element does not generate optimal answer. Suppose A={1,8,9,7,6}-  with lowes element swap is {8,6} so cost=14, Resultant A={1,6,9,7,8},next  swap{7,9} cost=(14)+16=30 , next swap {8,9}=17 so total cost=30+17=47.where optimal solution is 42.

Comment: your source array is 8 4 5 3 2 7, your target 2 3 4 5 7 8. So: Swap 2 with 7, swap 2 with 8. Now you're at step 3. You have the array [2 4 5 3] to convert into [2 3 4 5]. So you have the choice between swapping 3 and 5, and then 3 and 4; or swapping 2 and 3, 2 and 5, 2 and 4, 2 and 3 again. Unless I missed something 2 <> 7, 2 <> 8, 3 <> 5, 3 <> 4, which is given by the algorithm, looks pretty good.

Comment: About 1 8 9 7 6. You're beginning at step 3 already. So in that case you should choose the second option of step 3: swap the lowest element (1) with the lowest element not at its final spot (6), proceed, and then swap them back. 1<>6, 1<>9, 1<>7, 1<>8, 1<>6, cost: 40.

Comment: Thanks a lot , Now everything make sense.

Comment: May I know if this solution guarantees the optimal solution? If so, how to prove?

Answer (score 2):

This smells like homework. What you need to do is sort the array but doing so while minimizing cost of swaps. So, it's a optimization problem rather than a sorting problem.

A greedy algorithm would despite this work, all you do is that you fix the solution by swapping the cheapest first (figuring out where in the list it belongs). This is however, not necessarily optimal.

As long as you never swap the same element twice a greedy algorithm should be optimal though.

Anyway, back to the dynamic programming stuff, just build your solution tree using recursion and then prune the tree as you find a more optimal solutions. This is pretty basic recursion.

If you a more complicated sorting algorithm you'll have a lot more difficulty puzzling that together with the dynamic programming so I suggest you start out with a simple, slow `O(n^2)` sort. And build on top of this.

Rather than to provide you with a solution, I'd like to explain how dynamic programming works in my own words.

- The first thing you need to do, is to figure out an algorithm that will explore all possible solutions (this can be a really stupid brute force algorithm).
- You then implement this using recursion because dynamic programming is based around being able to figure out overlapping sub problems quickly, ergo recursion.
- At each recursive call you look up where you are in your solution and check where you've computed this part of the solution tree before, if you have done this, you can test whether the current solution is *more optimal*, if it is then you continue, otherwise you're done with this *branch* of the problem.
- When you arrive at the final solution you will have solved the problem.

Think of each recursive call as a snapshot of a partial solution. It's your job to figure how each recursive call fits together in the final optimal solution.

This what I recommend you do:

1. Write a recursive sort algorithm
2. Add a parameter to your recursive function that maintains the cost of this execution path, as you sort the array, add to this cost. For every possible swap at any given point do another recursive call (this will branch your solution tree)
3. Whenever you realize that the cost of the solution you are currently exploring exceeds what you already have somewhere else, abort (just return).

To be able to answer the last question you need to maintain shared memory area in which you can index depending on where you are in you're recursive algorithm. If there's a precomputed cost there you just return that value and don't continue processing (this is the pruning, which makes it fast).

Using this method you can even base your solution on a permutation brute force algorithm, it will probably be very slow or memory intensive because it is stupid when it comes to when you *branch* or *prune* but you don't really need a specific sort algorithm to make this work, it will just be more efficient to go about it that way.

Good luck!

Comment: In fact i am  looking for a tabular solution rather than bruteforce+ pruning . Is it not possible to obtain a optimal subproblem which leads to optimal solution??

Comment: What do you mean by *tabular*? Using a brute force algorithm is just easiest thing to start with, if you use something more cleaver then you'll have a faster, but more complex algorithm.

Comment: Yes , brute force is easier but what will be its time complexity. Will it work for 1000 element??

Comment: Brute force is not slow if the first solution you compute is optimal, or a good approximation. This is why dynamic programming and a decent approximation can be used to solve problems fast, despite having an initial search algorithm which is largely just brute force.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a high-low selection sort, you can guarantee that the Nth greatest element isn't swapped more than N times. This a simple algorithm with a pretty easy and enticing guarantee... Maybe check this on a few examples and see how it could be tweaked. Note: this may not lead to an optimal answer...

Answer (score -1):

To find the absolute minimal cost you'll have to try all ways to swap and then find the fastest one.

```
def recsort(l, sort):
  if sorted(l2):
    if min>cost:
      cost=min
      bestsort=sort
  if(len(sort) > len(l)*len(l)): //or some other criteria
    return

  for p1 in (0,len(l)):
    for p2 in (0,len(l)):
      cost += l[p1] + l[p2]
      l2 = swap(l, p1,p2)
      if cost<min:
        recsort(l2, append sort (p1,p2))
```

An approach that will be pretty good is to recursively place the biggest value at the top.

Comment: What makes you say you have to try all ways? That statement needs a proof.

Comment: True. That is an NP vs P problem though, thus not provable. And I'm sorry, I didn't mean all ways, but a non-polynomial amount of ways. All other algorithms described here are search algorithms that are in NP.

Comment: Proving that something is NP is doable. That's what you have to do.

Comment: That means I'll have to prove there is no algorithm in P that solves this, which is impossible? I can only prove that an algorithm is in NP, not that a problem is.

Comment: If we restate the problem as this: There are polynomial amount of solutions, find the fastest. There is no inherent ordering in them, thus it needs to check NP amount of them, thus the problem is NP-hard. Now I'll only have to prove that there is no inherent ordering in them...

Comment: No, you can prove that a problem is in NP. Algorithms have no complexity classes, problems do. An algorithm is not in P or NP, a problem is. Your algorithm is exponential, and you are saying there is no polynomial algorithm for this problem, which needs proof. A proof that is most likely impossible judging from the problem formulation and data bounds (it's probably from a contest).